# HTML/CSS Ribbon List Within List

Tags: html, css

I've created a ribbon on the homepage of my site (home, about, story) in a horizontal line using only HTML and CSS. The "Story" button brings out a drop-down menu of two items. My question is this: How can I use a similar method in order to cause a drop-"right" menu to appear next to one of the options that dropped down from the main ribbon? I've included pictures and the code below. I realize this is probably extremely convoluted; I'm a beginner.

Code (HTML):

```
<div id="animatedRibbon">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="sub-menu-parent"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="sub-menu-parent"><a href="#">Story</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub-sub-menu-parent2015">2015</a>
                        <ul class="sub-sub-menu2015">
                            <li class="option2015"><a href="#">March</a></li>
                            <li class="option2015"><a href="#">April</a></li>
                            <li class="option2015"><a href="#">May</a></li>
                            <li class="option2015"><a href="#">June</a></li>
                            <li class="option2015"><a href="#">July</a></li>
                            <li class="option2015"><a href="#">August</a></li>
                            <li class="option2015"><a href="#">September</a>                </li>
                            <li class="option2015"><a href="#">October</a></li>
                            <li class="option2015"><a href="#">November</a></li>
                            <li class="option2015"><a href="#">December</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub-sub-menu-parent-2016">2016</a>
                        <ul class="sub-sub-menu2016">
                            <li class="option2016"><a href="#">January</a></li>
                            <li class="option2016"><a href="#">February</a></li>
                            <li class="option2016"><a href="#">March</a></li>
                            <li class="option2016"><a href="#">April</a></li>
                            <li class="option2016"><a href="#">May</a></li>
                            <li class="option2016"><a href="#">June</a></li>
                            <li class="option2016"><a href="#">July</a></li>
                            <li class="option2016"><a href="#">August</a></li>
                            <li class="option2016"><a href="#">September</a></li>
                            <li class="option2016"><a href="#">October</a></li>
                            <li class="option2016"><a href="#">November</a></li>
                            <li class="option2016"><a href="#">December</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="sub-menu-parent"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </nav> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sub-menu-parent { position: relative; }

.sub-menu { 
  visibility: hidden; /* hides sub-menu */
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-1em);
  z-index: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.3s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s;}

.sub-menu-parent:hover .sub-menu {
  visibility: visible; /* shows sub-menu */
  opacity: 0.85;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.3s; /* this removes the transition delay so the menu will be visible while the other styles transition */}


.sub-sub-menu2015 {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateX(2em);
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.3s, z-index 0s linear 0.51s;}

.sub-sub-menu2016 {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateX(2em);
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.3s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s;}

.sub-sub-menu-parent2015:hover .sub-sub-menu2015 {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0.85;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: translateY(0%);
    transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.3s;}

/* presentational */
/*body { padding: 2%; font: 18px/1.4 sans-serif; }*/

nav a { color: #E00; display: block; padding: 0.5em 1em; text-decoration: none;}
nav a:hover { color: #F55; }
nav ul,
nav ul li { list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; }

nav > ul { background: #ffdead; text-align: center; }
nav > ul > li { display: inline-block; border-left: solid 1px #aaa; }
nav > ul > li:first-child { border-left: none; }

.sub-menu {
  background: #ffdead;}

nav > ul > li > a:link {
    font-size: 36px;}

nav > ul > li > a:hover, 
nav > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover {
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff,
        0 0 20px #fff,
        0 0 30px #fff,
        0 0 40px #74AFAD,
        0 0 70px #74AFAD,
        0 0 80px #74AFAD,
        0 0 100px #74AFAD,
        0 0 150px #74AFAD;}

nav > ul > li > ul > li > a:link {
    font-size: 18px;}

#animatedRibbon {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;}
```

Here are some images detailing exactly what I'm talking about.
[Main menu ribbon with drop down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqfAl.png)
[Desired effect (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKeda.png)

Comment: creating the scenario with jquery will work?? or you need only css

Comment: Preferably only CSS... I'm still pretty new to JS/jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minor change in your *CSS* will give you desired effect you wanted for your `sub-sub-menus`.

Here's the **CSS**:

```
ul[class*="sub-sub-menu"] {
  background: #ffdead;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.3s;
}

.sub-menu-parent .sub-menu li {
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu-parent .sub-menu li:hover .sub-sub-menu2015,
.sub-menu-parent .sub-menu li:hover .sub-sub-menu2016 {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.85;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

Here, I have also created a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/o8zmtz71)